# reordering of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to reorder dimensions of my numpy array. The following piece of code works but it's too slow.

```
for i in range(image_size):
    for j in range(image_size):
        for k in range(3):
            new_im[k, i, j] = im[i, j, k]
```

After this, I vectorize the new_im:

```
new_im_vec = new_im.reshape(image_size**2 * 3)
```

That said, I don't need new_im and I only need to get to new_im_vec. Is there a better way to do this? image_size is about 256.

Comment: If you are using Python2, you can use `xrange` instead of `range`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [rollaxis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy.rollaxis), a function which shifts the axes around, allowing you to reorder your array in a single command. If `im` has shape *i, j, k*

```
rollaxis(im, 2)
```

should return an array with shape *k, i, j*.

After this, you can flatten your array, [ravel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel) is a clear function for this purpose. Putting this all together, you have a nice one-liner:

```
new_im_vec = ravel(rollaxis(im, 2))
```

Comment: Cool! it works. The other thing I need to do is to mirror in the first dimension. swap a[1, :, :] and a[3, :, :]. Is there a function for this?

Comment: @Mohammad Moghimi, If I understand your question correctly, you can use flipud to flip the array about the horizontal axis. a[::-1,:,:] should also work.

Comment: +1 Probably the best option. For completeness, there is also the option (which I believe is actually called by `np.rollaxis`) of doing `np.transpose(im, (2, 0, 1))`. As an aside note, `np.rollaxis` or `np.transpose` return a view of the original data, but when calling flatten on that view, a copy is likely to be triggered.

Answer (score 8):

```
new_im = im.swapaxes(0,2).swapaxes(1,2) # First swap i and k, then i and j
new_im_vec = new_im.flatten() # Vectorize
```

This should be much faster because swapaxes returns a view on the array, rather than copying elements over.

And of course if you want to skip `new_im`, you can do it in one line, and still only `flatten` is doing any copying.

```
new_im_vec = im.swapaxes(0,2).swapaxes(1,2).flatten()
```

Comment: swapaxes is awesome! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

With einops:

```
x = einops.rearrange(x, 'height width color -> color height width')
```

Pros:

- you see how axes were ordered in input
- you see how axes are ordered in output
- you don't need to think about steps you need to take (and e.g. no need to remember which direction axes are rolled)